# Ingress configuration

Tags: dns, azure-aks

Please refer to the corresponding section of the following URL. "Configure a DNS name"
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-tls
Only the server name is specified for the creation of the DNS name.
However, in "Create a certificate object", it is demo-aks-ingress.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com and it is "eastus". Should this be replaced with "eastjp"? I replaced it, but "Test the ingress configuration" does not work.

If my AKS Cluster is running on eastjp server, the name should be "xxxxxx.eastjs.cloudapp.azure.com"?

Comment: Any more questions?

Answer (score 2):

In the document, you create the custom certificate with the DNS name of a public IP for the Ingress. You just can set the prefix of the DNS name, and the remaining part of the DNS name is a Fixed combination in Azure, and the whole name will be as domainnamelabel.location.cloudapp.azure.com. See the description [DNS hostname resolution of a Public IP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-ip-addresses-overview-arm#dns-hostname-resolution).

So if the "eastjp" you mean a location that Azure support, it will be done. If not, it won't work. And when you create a public IP in a different region for your ingress, it will come out a timeout. Under this circumstance, the DNS name of the public IP could only have the location the same with your AKS cluster.